# vs code shift to the left by 2 spaces after ';' as it was by default ( tab = 2 spaces)

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I have written something( let's say print('...')) and put a semicolon everything is shift to the left by 2 spaces. In the settings, I installed :"editor.tabSize": 4, "editor.insertSpaces": true, "editor.detectIndentation": false, but it still automatically continues to shift everything to the left. Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My5Lt.jpg)

I realized that I should have disabled this option in the settings.